# Ubuntu 18.04 Google chrome could not launch after installation

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome

I tried to install Google Chrome using  `sudo apt-get install -f ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

Installation seems for the first glance that everything is ok but when I try to run google chrome
It gives me error: `There was an error launching the application.`

Log from installation:

```
sudo apt-get install -f ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'google-chrome-stable' instead of './google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bsdtar cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin db-util db5.3-util extlinux fonts-lato hfsplus icoutils
  javascript-common ldmtool libafflib0v5 libarchive-tools libbfio1 libconfig9 libdate-manip-perl
  libewf2 libfwup1 libguestfs-hfsplus libguestfs-perl libguestfs-reiserfs libguestfs-tools
  libguestfs-xfs libguestfs0 libhfsp0 libhivex0 libintl-perl libintl-xs-perl libjs-jquery
  libldm-1.0-0 libruby2.5 libsodium-dev libstring-shellquote-perl libsys-virt-perl libtsk13
  libwin-hivex-perl lsscsi pkg-config rake ruby ruby-bcrypt-pbkdf ruby-blankslate ruby-builder
  ruby-childprocess ruby-did-you-mean ruby-domain-name ruby-erubis ruby-excon ruby-ffi ruby-fog-core
  ruby-fog-json ruby-fog-libvirt ruby-fog-xml ruby-formatador ruby-http-cookie ruby-i18n ruby-json
  ruby-libvirt ruby-listen ruby-log4r ruby-mime-types ruby-mime-types-data ruby-minitest
  ruby-multi-json ruby-net-scp ruby-net-sftp ruby-net-ssh ruby-net-telnet ruby-netrc ruby-nokogiri
  ruby-oj ruby-pkg-config ruby-power-assert ruby-rb-inotify ruby-rbnacl ruby-rest-client ruby-sqlite3
  ruby-test-unit ruby-unf ruby-unf-ext ruby2.5 rubygems-integration scrub sleuthkit sqlite3 supermin
  vagrant-libvirt zerofree
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  google-chrome-stable
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 63,6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 224 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 google-chrome-stable amd64 80.0.3987.132-1 [63,6 MB]
Fetched 63,6 MB in 8s (7 660 kB/s)                                                                    
Selecting previously unselected package google-chrome-stable.
(Reading database ... 191242 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../google-chrome-stable_80.0.3987.132-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (80.0.3987.132-1) ...
Setting up google-chrome-stable (80.0.3987.132-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/x-www-browser (x-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser (gnome-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/google-chrome (google-chrome) in auto mode
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next:

```
sudo apt purge google-chrome-stable && sudo apt autoremove
```

Make sure you have the right repository listed in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Then do the next:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
sudo apt-key add linux_signing_key.pub
sudo apt update
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```

You could also try not stable versions:

```
sudo apt install google-chrome-beta
sudo apt install google-chrome-unstable
```

Comment: Command 'deb' not found. What do you mean by this:?  `deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`

Comment: it's not a command but content of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` file. Edit it with your preferable editor using `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list/google-chrome.list` or whatever you prefer. You could just say if you see it. You can do a `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`  to show what it contains

Comment: It was set right. ### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
`deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`

Comment: That's ok. then you could proceed further:). If stable version will refuse launching, you could try `beta` or `unstable` version of chrome.

Comment: I tried all options. E: Package 'google-chrome-stable' has no installation candidate

Comment: During `sudo apt update` did you see the next: `Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release`?

Comment: And also, during `wget https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub &&
sudo apt-key add linux_signing_key.pub` commands execution, what is the output?

Comment: Yeah, it installed but problem is the same. To be honest I found that I have to run it by root and no-sandbox. 
`sudo /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
[20744:20744:0309/223349.372286:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.` then it opens but I don't know why not normal mode is working :(

I have to type:
 `sudo /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --no-sandbox`

Comment: have you tried beta version? What does `ls -ailh .config/ | grep google` show?

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package google-chrome-unstable

Comment: What it offers when you trying to run: `sudo apt install google-chrome*`?

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'`